# Apache Rewrite rule matches and overwriting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm really new to regular expressions and I'm having a hard time on fixing my rewrite rules.

The current structure is this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^data.js$ /data.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(profile|photo)/?(.*)$ /index.php [NC]
```

Everything works fine if I'm only looking for `/profile` or `/photo` views. But I'd like to automatically allow `/messages` or `/settings` for example because everytime a new `view` will be added , the htaccess will require modifications on those `alternative literals` too. Now, my question is how replace that `matching group` in order to allow any link like this:

```
/
/segment
/segment/?(.*)
```

I tried allowing everything but I end up with "Internal Server Error":

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Also tried `^(.*)$` and other options too.. also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\.])/?(.*)$ /index.php
```

In order to allow any alphanumeric word, but I still end up with "Internal Server Error", I know I'm messing up the square brackets with `match any of content` .. can someone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^data\.js$ data.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api.php [NC,L]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Okay, this is correct, but, can you explain me how are these working ? I mean.. are they like, combining first rewrite condition, `if not valid directory && not valid filename` then `execute rewrite rule` ? And if so, why is that dot used and not `.*` ( dot asterisk to multiply the any char thingy ).

Comment: Yes this is basically same thing I added in my comments that **if not valid directory && not valid filename then forward every request to index.php**. DOT is to make sure we are not forwarding home page but `.*` also can be used without any problem

Comment: I can only accept answers within 10 minutes since I asked the question. And I was going to sleep.

Comment: if you're kind enough to tell me, rather than just asking another question, if I'm doing another rewrite rule after the last rewrite rule, is it following those conditions or is it just like other programming languages, taking only the first rule after conditions ?

Comment: If you are adding a new rule like first 2 rules then make sure to place them **before** last rule since that is a catch-all generic rule.

Comment: I'm bothering you again but since there are tons of questions like this I decided to not create a new question. You have any idea how to apply these rules to nginx ? Converting them using online tools does not solve my problem.

Comment: Actually I don't know nginx well to be able to give you a good answer on that. I would suggest create a new question with your attempted nginx rules and experts here will sure help you out.